# Motion (Apple FCP animation software) change project frame size resolution height and width?

Tags: animation, motion, finalcut

My Final Cut Pro movie is 2048x1556, 60 fps.

[image]

When I import it into Motion it's cropped. It looks like Motion is set for 1080 resolution. How do I change the resolution of Motion to fit the FCP movie? According to [Apple's documentation](https://support.apple.com/guide/motion/project-frame-size-motn946cb0e8/mac), you use `the Width and Height parameters in the Properties Inspector`. Are they talking about `Inspector > Properties`? I don't see any width or height parameters.

[image]

Is there a way to start a project with a Final Cut Pro movie and have the Motion project automatically configure itself to the FCP movie?

I'm using Motion 5.4.6 and FCP 10.4.9.

Answer (score 1):

The [Edit project properties in Motion](https://support.apple.com/guide/motion/edit-project-properties-motnb8ca82dd/mac) documentation shows how to change frame size. You click `Inspector > Properties` and `Layers > Project`. Now `Width` and `Height` appear under `Properties` and you can change these.

[image]